# Is it possible to view configuration files of an Angular.js app on production?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I was recently working with a company developing an Angular.js web app. They were using Firebase as their database solution, and inside their app config file under `app` directory, they're using a Firebase secret key to bypass the authentication with Firebase.

I was wondering, how secure is it? Can someone read that Firebase key on production through DevTools or some other method? Is it good practice to use authentication credentials in configuration files? Does uglifying those files help in any ways?

Update:

They were using the secret key in both the Angular.js app and one of the Node.js servers (they had multiple repositories).

I want to know how secure is the secret key in the app as opposed to the server?

Comment: Answer for a pure AngularJS app below. But you also tagged with node.js. Can you explain how that fits into the app architecture?

Comment: Since the company also had servers that weren't using angular but Node.js only and used configuration files in the same manner as the app.

Comment: This description is unclear now. Is this an AngularJS app that uses the secret to connect to Firebase? Or is it an AngularJS app that connects to a custom back-end that mints custom tokens to connect to Firebase? The two scenarios are *very* different and without a single clear description, we can't help. Provide all details in the question please, draw a diagram if needed.

Comment: I'm curious to know the answer in both scenarios for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the secret of a Firebase database, gives you administrator level access to that database. It should therefor not be shared with the users of your app, unless you comfortable with all of them accessing your database. And if you are comfortable with that, you might as well not implement security rules anyway.

If it is a pure AngularJS app with no server component except for Firebase, all would have to code run in the user's browser. That means the secret would be in the user's browser, which as explained is a security risk.

Uglifying/obfuscating the files doesn't help significantly: the value will still be there. The solution is to have the users properly authenticate, so that you can secure the database against unauthorized access.

Comment: So if the Firebase secret key is only running on the server and the app authenticates users to the server, those authentication keys are in the browser. Can't the server authentication credentials be exposed? And a third-party authenticate himself as the user?

Comment: In other words, how does server authentication works compared to firebase authentication?